# How can preload images present in a directory and display them as part of the default upload page of blueimp file upload plugin for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, blueimp

I have a set of images in a directory which are loaded from the database. I need to preload these images and display them in the file list of the default upload page of blueimp file- upload plugin. I'm unable to find anything concrete about this issue. Any help will be much appreciated.